# How do I sign into my clients Wordpress admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, server

My client wants me to make some styling edits to their Wordpress website, but I am unable to access their Wordpress admin page. The website is linked to an external database server, and he has supplied me with the server address (E.g. http://34.43.321.234), the HTTP Auth for admin page, and the Wordpress login. How would I sign in to the admin page?

Comment: Do you know the domain name? have you tried `http://[domain]/wp-admin` or whatever the admin page for wp is.

Comment: just open the server address?? even if it's not masked with an url you should still be able to open it normaly. If that doesn't work ask him for the URL you need to open it.

Comment: @Halcyon Adding wp-admin to the end worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To access the WordPress dashboard you simply need to add /wp-admin to the end of the URL, e.g. http://34.43.321.234/wp-admin

Comment: +1.  Though it's worth noting that'll change if WordPress is running out of a subdirectory (if `WordPress Address (URL)` has been changed in the admin console), in which case you'd have to look at the source of one of the pages and look for (say) the stylesheet URL and work out the prefix.

Comment: @ChristopherHill please, close questions when you get answer